# How to add more than two plugins in a next.config.js

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, sass, next.js

I wanted to implement sass and BEM methodology to our company's project, however, I am having little trouble adding sass plugin to existing code. Currently, out we are using typescript and CSS plugin.

```
const path = require('path')
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const configuration = require('./config/configuration.json')

module.exports = withTypescript(
  withCSS({
      webpack(config) {
        if (process.env.ANALYZE) {
          config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'server',
            analyzerPort: 8888,
            openAnalyzer: true,
          }))
        }
        return config
      },
      cssModules: true,
      serverRuntimeConfig: { 
        // Will only be available on the server side
      },
      publicRuntimeConfig: { 
        // Will be available on both server and client
      }
    })
  )
```

I wanted to add sass plugin without still be able to work on the project while I implement sass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to add more plugins.

In your `webpack(config) { /* ... */ }` function, you can keep pushing more plugins into `config.plugins`.

For example, here I've added the `WebpackBar` plugin that profiles your build script.

```
webpack(config) {
    if (process.env.ANALYZE) {
        config.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'server',
            analyzerPort: 8888,
            openAnalyzer: true,
        }))
    }

    config.plugins.push(new WebpackBar({
        fancy: true,
        profile: true,
        basic: false,
    }));

    // just do as many config.plugins.push() calls as you need

    return config
},
```